# Issue with widget ratingbar in listview

Tags: android, android-widget

My application involves parsing an XML file online that contains data on hotels (name, address, category) but when I try to manage the star rating bar defined for the category of hotels 1 star, 2 star ... I am not successful.
First look at my XML file:

```
    <hotels count="2">
<hotel>
<name>el mouradi</name>
<place>hammamet</place>
<category>5</category>
</hotel>
<hotel>
<name>caralton</name>
<place>tunis</place>
<category>4</category>
</hotel>
</hotels>
```

This is my class in Main.java. I could import the Xml file data as a table, then view the data as a string in the list view without a problem:

```
   package com.hotel.tn;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import com.pxr.tutorial.xmltest.R;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
//import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends ListActivity {
     private ListView list;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. 
     * @param stars */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);
        list = getListView();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        String xml = XMLfunctions.getXML();
        Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(xml);

        int numResults = XMLfunctions.numResults(doc);

        if((numResults <= 0)){
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "pas de resultas", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            finish();
        }

        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("hotel");         
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {                           
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    

            Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);
            map.put("cat", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "categorie"));
            map.put("nom",XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "nom"));
            map.put("adr",XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "adr"));

            mylist.add(map);            
        }       


        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,mylist,R.layout.main, 
                      new  String[]{"nom","adr","cat"}, 
                       new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle,R.id.item_su});


      list.setAdapter(adapter);
       }}
```

This is Listeadapter.java.

Eclipse shows me the following error: "the method get int type in the list not applicable for the argument string" at this line `rating.setRating (List.get ("cat")` .

If I try to replace `"cat"` with an integer in the line `List.get("cat")` I could run the application but the rating bar doesn't change.  What could be wrong?

```
package com.hotel.tn;

//import android.app.ListActivity;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.pxr.tutorial.xmltest.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class Listeadapter extends SimpleAdapter  {

    private LayoutInflater  mInflater;
    public Listeadapter (Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data,
            int resource, String[] from, int[] to)
    {
        super (context, data, resource, from, to);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from (context);
    }
        public Object getItem (int position)
        {
            return getItem (position);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

            if (convertView == null){
                // holder = new ViewHolder(); 


                convertView = mInflater.inflate (R.layout.main, null);

                // holder.
                RatingBar rating = (RatingBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);

                rating.setRating(List.get(cat));/*or rating.setRating(2); dont work **/
                rating.setTag (position);

                // convertView.setTag(holder); 

            }
            return super.getView (position, convertView, parent);
        } }
```